# How to bind Child object records with Radio button on VF page

Tags: visualforce

I have master-detail relationship between two objects. Master is Question__c and detail is Question_options__c. Question_c object contains question for example: Where do you live?

and Question_options__c contains options for this question like this:

- India
- USA
- Canada

I want to  bind Question_options__c with radio buttons on vf page.I am able to get the master and child records in SOQL query in apex class and l also put the logic to bind child records related to master with radio buttons but, it binds all the child records with radio button. Here is my apex and vf page code:

VF Page:

```
<div class="form-style-6">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <apex:form >
    <apex:repeat value="{!quelistradio}" var="qr" >
        <th>{!qr.Name}</th>
        <div >
            <apex:repeat value="{!qr.Question_Options__r}" var="child" >
                 <apex:selectRadio id="radiobtn" value="{!selectradival}" >
              <apex:selectOption id="Radiobtnopn" value="{!child.Option1__c}"/>
                </apex:selectRadio> 
            </apex:repeat>
        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
    <apex:repeat value="{!quelisttext}" var="qt" >
        <th>{!qt.Name}</th>
        <input type="text" name="textinput" id="inputelement"/> 
    </apex:repeat>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="pre_chatsubmit"  onclick="dosave();false">Submit
    </button>
        </apex:form>
</div>       
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
queradiquestionoptions= new List<Question_Options__c>();
quelisttext = new List<Post_Chat_Question__c>();
quelistradio= new List<Post_Chat_Question__c>();
quelistcheckbox = new List<Post_Chat_Question__c>();
quelisttext=  [Select id,Name,Question_Type__c,Sequence__c,
  (Select Id,Name,Option1__c,PostChatQuestion__c from Question_Options__r) from Post_Chat_Question__c Where Question_Type__c=:'Text'  ORDER BY Sequence__c];
quelistradio= [Select id,Name,Question_Type__c,Sequence__c,
  (Select Id,Name,Option1__c,PostChatQuestion__c from Question_Options__r) from Post_Chat_Question__c Where Question_Type__c=:'Radio'  ORDER BY Sequence__c];
quelistcheckbox=[Select id,Name,Question_Type__c,Sequence__c,
  (Select Id,Name,Option1__c,PostChatQuestion__c from Question_Options__r) from Post_Chat_Question__c Where Question_Type__c=:'Checkbox'  ORDER BY Sequence__c];

}
public  List<SelectOption>  getitems(){
  questoqueoptions = new Map<Id,List<Question_Options__c>>();
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(Post_Chat_Question__c qoc:quelistradio){

        questoqueoptions.put(qoc.id,qoc.Question_Options__r);
        system.debug('###MAPOFQUESTIONANDOPTIONS'+questoqueoptions);
    }

    for(Post_Chat_Question__c pcq:quelistradio){
          //List<Question_Options__c> listofoptions = new  List<Question_Options__c>();
        if(questoqueoptions.containskey(pcq.id)){

            listofoptions=  questoqueoptions.get(pcq.id);
             system.debug('###LISTOFOPTIONS'+listofoptions);
            for(Question_Options__c qo:listofoptions){  options.add(new selectOption(qo.Option1__c, qo.Option1__c));}

        }
    }


    return options; 

}
```

As you can see, The master record is How would you rate this?

and related child records are Good,Very Good,Excellent,Average

But it also display other child records which are not related to this master record e.g Yes No[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of problems are best handled using wrapper classes

```
public class QuestionRadioWrapper {
   public Post_Chat_Question__c q {get; private set;}
   public SelectOption[] getOptions() {
     SelectOption[] options = new List<SelectOption>();
     for (Question_Option__c qo = this.q.Question_Options__r) {
       options.add(new SelectOption(qo.Option1__c,qo.Option1__c);
     return options;
   }
   public String selectedRadio {get; set;}
   public QuestionRadioWrapper(Post_Chat_Question__c q) {this.q. = q;}
}
public QuestionRadioWrapper[] qRadios {
  get {
     qRadios = new List<QuestionRadioWrapper>();
     for (Post_Chat_Question__c q: 
      [SELECT id,Name,Question_Type__c,Sequence__c,
        (Select Id,Name,Option1__c,PostChatQuestion__c from Question_Options__r) 
       FROM Post_Chat_Question__c Where Question_Type__c=:'Radio'  
       ORDER BY Sequence__c] (
        qRadios.add(new QuestionRadioWrapper(q);
     }
     return qRadios;
  } private set;
}
```

Then your VF page is:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!qRadios}" var="qR">
   <apex:outputField value="{!qR.q.Name}"/>
   <apex:selectRadio value="{!qR.selectedRadio}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!qR.options}"/>
   </apex:selectRadio>
</apex:repeat>
```

I omitted the table formatting from my answer

Comment: Thank you Crop It was really helpful. I was able to get through!